# Recommended inexpensive heart-rate monitors?

Tags: product-rec, training, frugal, heart-rate

Since I last used a heart rate monitor (about eight years ago), wrist-watch only monitors seem to have increased in popularity (based on the offerings at [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_i_1?rh=k%3aheart+rate+monitor,i%3asporting&keywords=heart+rate+monitor&ie=UTF8&qid=1291955116#/ref=sr_nr_p_4_1?rh=k%3Aheart+rate+monitor%2Cn%3A3375251%2Cp_4%3APolar%7CTimex&bbn=3375251&sort=salesrank&keywords=heart+rate+monitor&ie=UTF8&qid=1291955170&rnid=219891011))

**update** apparently these watches come with a chest strap, although the chest-strap is not included in the product description..

In the 90's and early 00's, heart rate monitors never lasted me more than a year or two before the signal or the contacts started to fail.

My primary question is ... can you recommended an inexpensive (<$50) monitor?

Comment: just to clarify you're looking for one that doesn't have a chest strap?

Comment: @Curtismchale - To clarify, I think this question has two parts, one asking for an inexpensive heart-rate monitor, the the other asking about wrist-vs-chest mount units.  @David, is this correct?

Comment: @neilfein, this is correct.

Comment: @David - Ive updated your question. Also, if you don't get any answers soon, splitting this into two separate questions *may* help. (I'm not certain why a wrist mount would be less accurate -- it's the same circulatory system, yes? -- but a quick web search shows that a lot of people assume a chest mount *would* be more accurate.)

Comment: @neilfein - Chest strap monitors basically work like an ECG, which reads electrical signals from your heart. Looks like most of the units with no chest-strap measure your pulse via your fingertips, requiring you to stop and touch the watch to get a reading. One's measuring the heart, the other's measuring the circulatory system. And very importantly: chest-strap allows for continuous monitoring.

Comment: I've never seen any wrist-only ones. Can somebody provide a link to one of them?

Comment: @Wilka actually, I guess these are not wrist-only even though the product info on Amazon doesn't always mention that there is a chest strap. So, I assumed that the most popular ones didn't have a chest strap.

Comment: @David, with the rewrite of this question, it's much more focused on the product recommendation, thanks for editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak about HRM's that do not use a chest strap as that's the only type that I have used (other than to play with in the store).  I find the ones with a chest strap to be completely hassle free, and I don't have to contort into a weird position to get a reading.

I've had great luck with HRM's from Timex and Nashbar in the $50 range, and like Polar but have never owned one.

If you do go with a chest strap type, the primary thing to watch out for in the lower-end range is the ability to change the strap battery.  Some have a sealed chest strap, so you either have to tear it apart and super-glue it back together, or replace the strap entirely.

Comment: Tip on the chest strap. Dry them after use - they turn on with conductivity, if you leave a layer of sweat they will keep transmitting.

Answer (score 3):

If you look for a cheap chest-strap HRM I can testify in favor of the Sigma PC15, which I used personally.

See a review [here](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/accessories/gadgets/heart-rate-monitors/product/pc-15-29604?_brc=1).

As for completely wristwatch HRM I never used them directly for the reason freiheit states in his comment and I wouldn't recommend them for cycling use.